# Vuex commit succeed but the ui or view only change when refresh browser (not reactive)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex, vuejs3

I want to ask about vuex...so I want to my comment section to reactively update when I submit a form comment. The current is the ui is change if i refresh browser. The dispatch is succeeded but the state of ui doesn't change. Thank you.

```
const store = createStore({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    userid: "",
    exp: "",
    userData: "",
    postData: "",
    singlePostData: "",
    commentData: {},
  },
mutations: { 
    postComment(state, { commentData }) {
      console.log(commentData);
      state.commentData = commentData;
},
  
actions: {
  addComment(context, usercredentials) {
      // console.log(id);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAPI
          .post(`/post/${usercredentials.id}/comments`, {
            name: usercredentials.name,
            comment: usercredentials.comment,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            context.commit("postComment", response.data);
            resolve();
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    },
}
})

//COMPONENT
  methods: {
    onSubmitComment(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.$store.dispatch("addComment", {
        id: this.postId,
        name: this.userData.name,
        comment: this.comment,
      });
    },
  },
  computed: mapState(["commentData", "userData"])
```

Comment: Show your **console.log** output and put **await** before **this.$store.dispatch** and **async** before **onSubmitComment** method

Comment: The code looks good - there is no need to add async/await. Check with Vue DevTools what is inside the Vuex store and what is the value of computed property `commentData` in your component.

Comment: the state data inside state store is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Vue.set() for changing the commentData.
It could be the reactivity caveat => https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Just a little interested, you intialize commentData as an object but is it? Maybe it's better to initialize it as an array :)

It's also maybe nice to use async/await.

I would do the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const store = createStore({
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    userid: '',
    exp: '',
    userData: '',
    postData: '',
    singlePostData: '',
    commentData: {}
  },

  mutations: {
    postComment (state, { commentData }) {
      // better to use Vue.set()
      Vue.set(state, 'commentData', commentData);
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async addComment ({ commit }, usercredentials) {

      const response = await getAPI.post(`/post/${usercredentials.id}/comments`, {
        name: usercredentials.name,
        comment: usercredentials.comment
      });

      commit('postComment', response.data);
    }
  }
}
);
```